# how can i put json to map in java

Tags: java, json, jackson

In my project, I have a json file like this.

```
  [
   {
      "Task": {
         "refType": "EM TASK ",
         "reference": "73-22-49-100-104",
         "engType": "A5",
         "DMC": "V2500-A0-73-22-4900-03A-251A-C",
         "subTasks": {
            "SUBTASK0": "73-22-49-110-054-001",
            "SUBTASK1": "73-22-49-110-054-002"
         }
      }
   }
]
```

I want to create a map with this json file. It can be like this
**{refType,reference,engType,DMC,subTasks}** To do this I wrote these codes

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        int k=0;
        try {
            JSONObject json=null;
            System.out.println("Reading JSON file from Java program");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\ftk1187\\Desktop\\jsonExample.json");
            JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) parser.parse(fileReader);
            ArrayList<String> subtasks=new ArrayList<String>();
            for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.size();i++)
            {
                json=(JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                JSONObject jsonValue = (JSONObject) json.get("Task");
                JSONObject subTasks = (JSONObject) jsonValue.get("subTasks");
                String reference = (String) jsonValue.get("reference");
                String refType = (String) jsonValue.get("refType");
                String engType = (String) jsonValue.get("engType");
                String dmc = (String) jsonValue.get("DMC");
                System.out.println("reference: " + reference);
                System.out.println("refType: " + refType);
                System.out.println("DMC: " + dmc);
                System.out.println("engType: " + engType);
                subtasks.addAll(subTasks.values());
                while(k<subtasks.size())
                {
                    System.out.println("SubTasks: "+subtasks.get(k));
                    k++;
                }
                ObjectMapper objectMapper=new ObjectMapper();
                Tasks map=objectMapper.readValue(fileReader, Tasks.class);
                System.out.println(map);
            }

class Tasks{
    private String engType;
    private String refType;
    private String reference;
    private String dmc;
    private String[] subTask;
    public String getEngType() {
        return engType;
    }
    public void setEngType(String engType) {
        this.engType=engType;
    }
    public String getRefType() {
        return refType;
    }
    public void setRefType(String RefType) {
        this.refType=RefType;
    }
    public String getReference() {
        return reference;
    }
    public void setReference(String Reference) {
        this.reference=Reference;
    }
    public String getDmc() {
        return dmc;
    }
    public void setDmc(String Dmc) {
        this.dmc=Dmc;
    }
    public String[] getSubTask() {
        return subTask;
    }
    public void setSubTask(String[] SubTask) {
        this.subTask=SubTask;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("{");
        sb.append(refType).append(",");
        sb.append(reference).append(",");
        sb.append(engType).append(",");
        sb.append(dmc).append(",");
        for(String subTask1:subTask) {
            sb.append(subTask1).append(",");
        }
        sb.append("}");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work for me. It gives me this error

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No
>   content to map due to end-of-input  at [Source: (FileReader); line: 1,
>   column: 0]    at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4344)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4189)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3218)
>     at DocFinder.doGet(DocFinder.java:89)   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

I don't know what I need to do. I want to use these parameters for create servlet redirect.

Comment: Could you share complete stack trace and json file data

Comment: Looks like the file you try to parse an json object while the actually json is an json array. So try to use a list / array of `Tasks` for the object mapper

Comment: You may need to also adapt your son. It can be simplified by putting just the task content without keys in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create `POJO` class which fits `JSON` payload. After that, read `JSON` payload as tree - as `JSON Array`. Iterate over it and convert each `Task` node to `Tasks` class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File jsonFile = new File("./src/main/resources/test.json");

        ObjectMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder().build();

        List<Tasks> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayNode array = (ArrayNode) mapper.readTree(jsonFile);
        array.forEach(item -> tasks.add(mapper.convertValue(item.get("Task"), Tasks.class)));

        System.out.println(tasks);
    }
}

class Tasks {
    private String engType;
    private String refType;
    private String reference;

    @JsonProperty("DMC")
    private String dmc;

    private Map<String, String> subTasks;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

Above code prints:

```
[Tasks{engType='A5', refType='EM TASK ', reference='73-22-49-100-104', dmc='V2500-A0-73-22-4900-03A-251A-C', subTasks={SUBTASK0=73-22-49-110-054-001, SUBTASK1=73-22-49-110-054-002}}]
```

Comment: I tried it but I get this error. **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot construct instance of `DocFinder$Tasks` (although at least one Creator exists): non-static inner classes like this can only by instantiated using default, no-argument constructor
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1]**

Comment: @mustafa53, make a class `Tasks` as static and it has to have public no arg constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
"subTasks": {
            "SUBTASK0": "73-22-49-110-054-001",
            "SUBTASK1": "73-22-49-110-054-002"
         }
```

Above code looks an **object** while it is defined as ***private String[] subTask;***

Use below structure

```
==================================

public class SubTasks
{
    private String SUBTASK;

    public void setSUBTASK(String SUBTASK){
        this.SUBTASK = SUBTASK;
    }
    public String getSUBTASK(){
        return this.SUBTASK;
    }
}

==================================

public class Task
{
    private String refType;

    private String reference;

    private String engType;

    private String DMC;

    private SubTasks subTasks;

    public void setRefType(String refType){
        this.refType = refType;
    }
    public String getRefType(){
        return this.refType;
    }
    public void setReference(String reference){
        this.reference = reference;
    }
    public String getReference(){
        return this.reference;
    }
    public void setEngType(String engType){
        this.engType = engType;
    }
    public String getEngType(){
        return this.engType;
    }
    public void setDMC(String DMC){
        this.DMC = DMC;
    }
    public String getDMC(){
        return this.DMC;
    }
    public void setSubTasks(SubTasks subTasks){
        this.subTasks = subTasks;
    }
    public SubTasks getSubTasks(){
        return this.subTasks;
    }
}

==================================

public class Base
{
    private Task Task;

    public void setTask(Task Task){
        this.Task = Task;
    }
    public Task getTask(){
        return this.Task;
    }
}
```

Comment: I still get the same error. In other questions, people creating json files manuelly, maybe problem can be this.

Comment: No... you must be getting problem because example I had given is having one variable called "SUBTASK" while your json contain "SUBTASK0" and "SUBTASK1" and so on... you need those variables in Subtask Object

Comment: I tried to call other variables but it doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem in that line `Tasks map=objectMapper.readValue(fileReader, Tasks.class);`
Because your json define list of object, your model is define for an object.

You should re-define your model as below:

```
@Data // lombok
public class TaskWrapper {
    @JsonAlias("Task")
    private Task task;

    @Data
    public class Task {
        private String refType;
        private String reference;
        private String engType;
        @JsonAlias("DMC")
        private String dmc;
        private Map<String, String> subTasks;
    }
}
```

And change that line to

```
List<TaskWrapper> tasks= t.readValue(fileReader, new TypeReference<List<TaskWrapper>>(){});
```